# Will the proxy provider know what I'm communicating via HTTPS?

Tags: proxy, https, internet-security

I'm in China and I must use proxies or VPNs to access a wide variety of overseas sites (like Google).

My school provides a free proxy for this purpose, and it declares that

> Your activities will be stored for 90 days. In case it is required by local authorities, we will provide it without prior notice.

My question is, does the proxy server know **what** (not *where* or *when*, obviously it does) I'm sending and receiving via HTTPS?

Isn't the SSL/TLS connection established between my computer and the target site? Or is it between the proxy server and target site?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: “My question is, does the proxy server know what (not where or when, obviously it does) I'm sending and receiving via HTTPS?” I guarantee due to the region you live in all activities are recorded.

Comment: When you use a proxy server, the connection is established between the proxy and target site.  Conceivably depending on the way the proxy is configured the computer you are on will have an additional root certificate so it fully trusts the proxy, allowing it to MITM (man-in-the-middle) you - if you think about it, acting as a MITM is exactly the job ofa proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.   When you use a proxy for HTTPS traffic then the proxy acts as your agent,and the proxy server gets to see your data unencrypted.  It is fairly trivial to log this as well.

Comment: You mean the SSL/TLS connection is established between the target site and the **proxy server** (instead of my computer)?

Comment: Yes.    (filler because SU does not like short answers)